# How to throttle webservice calls in a C# windows application

Tags: c#, web-services

My application needs to call a WebService method to upload some xml.

The provider of this WebService has a restriction that my application cannot make more than 900 calls within a minute else it would be banned.

What kind of logic do I implement in my C# program which uses this webmethod to take care that more than 900 calls are not done in a minute.

Please note that I am not using WCF but simple httpwebrequest in my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No i think counter is not suitable at this places because how will we manage it as we require it every 900th call .

Comment: Show us some code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, you can count how many calls have been made and stop if it exceeds 900. Also reset this counter every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a fixed sized queue of 900 elements.  Push the timestamp in there for every call.

Before a pushing (every call), check the timestamp on the bottom end.  If less than 1 min, do it.  If more, fail or wait until it get to 1 minute